# What is the bes practice when moving from multiple virtual directories on iis into a single one?

Tags: .net, iis, url

We have an application that duplicate itself into seperate virtual directories so we can differ between our customers.(example: mySite/customer1)
Now, we need to change the way the system works.

We want all of the customers to use the same site.
So we need a single url but with some query string or other token for their organization.
(example: mySite?id=customer1)

What is the best way to make this change to an existing software?
maybe url re-writing or re-routing?

We trying to find a way to this with minimum refactoring to the code.

Any ideas?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

you can have multiple domains, or host names, all mapped to the same IIS Application/Site, in your code you should check the `Request.Headers["HOST"]` and not the query string.

Imagine if a customer changes the query string parameter to access his concurrent's web site!

you should have security in place and database handling everything correctly, meaning that you still connect to different databases probably, one per customer.

Read this one, should explain you enough to start: [Multiple domains, same web application on IIS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273136/multiple-domains-same-web-application-on-iis-6)